# Grunt Compress without root folder

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compress

I'm trying to compress a directory using grunt. I have tried the following sections in my grunt file.

```
compress: {
    main: {
       options: {
           archive: 'dist/output.zip',
           mode: 'zip'
       },
       files: [{
           src: ['build/*'],
           cwd: 'build',
           expand: true
       }]
    }
}
```

which gives me an empty zip file. Or

```
    compress: {
        main: {
            options: {
                archive: 'dist/output.zip',
                mode: 'zip'
            },
            files: [{
                src: ['build/*']
            }]
        }
    }
```

which gives me the following structure in my zip file

```
output.zip
 - build
   - my files
```

but I would like to remove the build directory to get

```
output.zip
 - my files
```

What changes can I make to get this structure?

Comment: For future readers: The key is that the `src` path is relative to the `cwd` path :) This is exactly what @Ryven has shown in his answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
compress: {
    main: {
       options: {
           archive: 'dist/output.zip',
           mode: 'zip'
       },
       files: [{
           src: ['**/*'],
           cwd: 'build/',
           expand: true
       }]
    }
}
```